# Команда ping windows

Tags: windows, ping, сеть

Команда ping выдает строку с таким значение  47ms 47ms 47msЧто эти цифры означают и почему они одинаковые?и вот такие 130ms 132ms 132msСпасибо!

Comment: извиняюсь команда tracert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уважаемый, в отчете же команда Вам пишет что это такое. Вот пример:

> Статистика Ping для ХХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ:
> Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0 (0% потерь),
> **Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:**
> Минимальное = 54 мсек, Максимальное = 54 мсек, Среднее = 54 мсек

Извиняюсь, приписку заметил позже: то же самое означают - время передачи пакета до хоста; по три одинаковых числа, это потому, что по-умолчанию до каждого из хостов отправляется по три пакета
[Вика: команда traceroute](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)